# I Need an Adhesive That Will Bond Aluminum to Plastic or Bakelite

Tags: motorcycle, kawasaki, plastic

I need to bond (or RE-bond) a piece of what appears to be a hard plastic lining onto a cam chain guide used in a Kawasaki KZ400H. It appears the OEM plastic piece was originally glued to the cam chain guide with some sort of adhesive, because it just came off when I tore down the engine. I need an adhesive that will bond permanently to aluminum and stand up to high temperature in an oil environment. I'm thinking about Pliobond 25, or something that I could heat the part with (if I have to) that would produce a very permanent bond, very important for a part that – if it came off and meshed with the engine's gears – could result in a very bad crash if it happened at speed. Any ideas?

Comment: Replacement of the part (with part glued to it) is probably wiser. This is my go to for gluing metal to phenolics, (you can speed the cure a lot with heat, or you can wait) not sure about the oil-bath aspect. https://www.ellsworth.com/products/adhesives/epoxy/resinlab-armstrong-a-12-epoxy-adhesive-110-g-tube-c-kit/ Just a happy customer. I like that it can be made stiffer or more flexible by altering the mix ratio, and I've used it on a serious structural project that had to be electrically insulated...

Comment: I threw a rod through the side of my lawn tractor engine block. I used JB Weld to glue the 2" piece back onto the block and it held for years despite the heat. Normal epoxy softens with heat.

Comment: I'd be very reluctant to use any sort of adhesive in this application.  Your best bet is to find a suitable replacement part.

Comment: That's not going to happen. Smooth aluminum or plastic are not bondable because they don't have any "jaggies" for the glue to bond to.